# Error when saving new workbook name

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I have been trying for most of the day to get this to work, but I can't figure out what is stopping the save process in this code:

```
Sheets("DailyReview").Select
Sheets("DailyReview").Copy
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
File_Name = "\\Il-svr\company\department\team\Schedules\Daily_Review_Email\city\" & Range("A110").Value & "\" & Range("D110").Value & "\DailyReview_" & Range("C110").Value & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=File_Name
```

The last line of code gives the error: "Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed. But a file actually does get renamed, just not "saved" to the path location. The path location is completely 100% correct and works fine when I save the macro workbook using the same path location. I am also using Excel 2010 and trying to save it in 2010 format. I have also tried setting the FileFormat to xlWorkbookDefault (51) with no success. I do have permission to save to this path and works fine if I save the new book manually. The ranges are just date values. For instance, the file would save as DailyReview_122914.xlsx if I used this code for today's date. I hope this is enough information. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Does the code use any references? I used to get this when a link to a reference was broken. You can check in the VBA editor by going to  Tools -> References and then looking if it says its not finding something. There are plenty of other things that cause this error though.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's using any references. Only the 4 main VBAProject selections are check marked. Like I said, if I save the main template file (macro workbook) using basically the same code, I don't get any errors and the file saves with the name and location it should. I should mention this is the entire code. Nothing precedes it or is after it (except Sub"" and End).

Comment: What values are in ranges `A110, D110, & C110`? Please validate that `File_Name` is a valid path and file name.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @RubberDuck. The values were blank for cell A110 which I think was throwing it off. I rewrote the code and discarded the value of cell A110 and it works fine now. It really is the simplest things some time. Thank you!